# How does positivity affect operator norms?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-lattices

Take a measure space $\Omega$, an exponent $1 \le p < \infty$ and a linear operator $T \colon L^p(\Omega) \to L^p(\Omega)$. Suppose that $T$ is *positive*, that is $Tf \ge 0$ a.e. if $f \ge 0$ almost everywhere. Then

$$\lVert T \rVert = \sup_{f \ge 0, \int_{\Omega} f^p \le 1} \lVert Tf \rVert_p;$$

that is, it suffices to take the supremum over positive functions.

I was wondering if there is something more general here. For example, does this hold if $T$ is an operator on $C(K)$ for compact $K$? Is this property true in some abstract class of Banach spaces?

Comment: In $C(K)$ you can simply use that every function in the unit ball satisfies $-1_{K} \leq f \leq 1_{K}$, where $1_{K}(x) = 1$ is the constant function. Using this you can even show that a positive operator is continuous (that's e.g. why measures on $K$ are the same thing as  positive linear functionals on $C(K)$). The general theory behind this is the theory of [Riesz spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_space) and Banach lattices. However, I find it hard to find a good exposition on that. If I'm not completely mistaken Yosida's book contains some stuff that might be of interest to you.

Comment: My remark on measures was maybe a bit of an overstatement. But that positivity implies continuity is a general theme in Riesz theory and often very useful. The order structure on Banach spaces is, if it interacts well with the norm, an extremely useful tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got my hands over Aliprantis and Burkinshaw's *Positive operators* (@t.b.: thank you for hints!) and read something on Riesz spaces and Banach lattices. A Banach lattice is a triple $(E, \le , \lVert \cdot \rVert )$, where

- $E$ is a real vector space.
- $\le$ is an ordering on $E$ compatible with vector space operations and s.t. for every $f, g\in E$ there exist $f \vee   g , f \wedge  g \in E$. We then define $\lvert f \rvert= f \vee (-f)$.
- $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is a Banach norm on $E$ s.t. $\lvert f \rvert \le \lvert g \rvert \Rightarrow \lVert f \rVert \le \lVert g \rVert$.

A *positive operator* on $E$ is then a linear operator that is order preserving. It is not obvious that every positive linear operator is continuous (cfr. Aliprantis & Burkinshaw, §4.3), hence bounded.

Now let $T$ be a positive operator on $E$. By definition

$$\lVert T \rVert= \sup_{\lVert f\rVert \le 1} \lVert Tf \rVert.$$

We claim that, being $T$ positive, it suffices to take the supremum over *positive* $f$ (that is, over all $f$ that are greater than the origin):

$$\lVert T \rVert = \sup_{\lVert f \rVert \le 1, f \ge 0} \lVert Tf \rVert.$$

In fact, it is clear that the second supremum is lesser than the first. To prove the reverse inequality take $\lVert f \rVert \le 1$ and observe that $ \lVert \lvert f \rvert \rVert \le 1$ also. We have $Tf \le T\lvert f \rvert$ and so $\lVert Tf \rVert \le \lVert T \lvert f \rvert \rVert$.

Comment: That's it, exactly! It wasn't that hard, was it?

Comment: No, not hard at all! The only difficulty was to wade through all of those new definitions and properties. But in doing so I discovered a very nice book!

Comment: I'll be sure to have a look at it (I guess you mean Aliprantis and Burkinshaw) because I don't know it, thanks a lot for this pointer! I agree that these definitions aren't that easy and fun to go through because they seem a bit unmotivated at first.